# jsoup unexpected behaviour and find all div for a class

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, jsoup

I am using jsoup to parse webpage using the following command

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.blablabla.de/").get();
```

then

```
System.out.println(document.toString());
```

I get the desired result. But saving the subject webpage and then trying to do the same operation

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("/user/test/test.html","UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

I got

```
html
head head
body
/home/1.html
body
html
```

My second issue is that I want to get the content of every single div of a specific class. I am using

```
Elements elements = document.select("div.things.subthings");
```

the divs I want to catch are as follows

```
<div class="col_a col text">
    <div class="text">
     done
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The next time you ask a question, please don't put two or more issues in the same question. `ONE question = ONE issue` ;)

Answer (score 2):

> But saving the subject webpage and then trying to do the same operation

The wrong method is called. Actually, the method called is this one:

```
static Document Jsoup::parse(String html, String baseUri) // Parse HTML into a Document.
```

You want to call this one:

```
static Document parse(File in, String charsetName) // Parse the contents of a file as HTML.
```

Try this instead:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("/user/test/test.html"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

---

> My second issue is that I want to get the content of every single div of a specific class.

Try one of the css queries below:

For finding all divs with `class="col_a col text"`

```
div.col_a.col.text
```

For finding all divs with `class="col_a col text"` OR `class="text"`

```
div.col_a.col.text, div.text
```

For finding all divs with `class="col_a col text"` having divs with `class="text"` among their descendants

```
div.col_a.col.text:has(div.text)
```